# Python struggling to understand for loops with a list

Tags: python

```
grid = [['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
       ['.', '0', '0', '.', '.', '.'],
       ['0', '0', '0', '0', '.', '.'],
       ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '.'],
       ['.', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
       ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '.'],
       ['0', '0', '0', '0', '.', '.'],
       ['.', '0', '0', '.', '.', '.'],
       ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']]

 def gridOutput(grid):
    for s in range(len(grid[0])):
        print()
        for i in range(len(grid)):
            print(grid[i][s],end='')
 gridOutput(grid)
```

This is printing out what I expect to be printed out. It is looping through the each element of each list by one. So like [0,1] [0,2] [0,3] [0,4] [0,5] etc

But I don't get how the code is doing this.

```
range(len(grid[0])):
```

Why use len when this returns the length of the list? and I don't get what [0] is doing, if i set it to any other integer up to 9 this works exactly the same.

Could someone please explain what this is doing, I have been trying to figure this out for 2 days and I now need some guidance.

Comment: Get the first grid item, get its length, then get a range of numbers from 0 to that length - 1. Changing the index doesn't change anything for you because all the grid items have the same length.

Comment: (There are better ways to do this printing *without* explicitly referring to the length of a list anywhere, but this code isn't using the better ways.)

Comment: grid[0] contains all your list grid[0][0] would contain the first array of your grid array

So grid[0] len should be 8
grid [0][0] len should be 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `len(grid)` that is only going to return the length of how many lists or 'rows' are in your grid. However, this does not tell you anything about the length of each list/row. To get that information, you access a list and get the length of that collection assuming they are all the same length.

`len(grid[0])` is going to give you the length of the first list (at index 0), which would be the amount of columns basically.

And why this is passed into the `range(x)` call is this is going to loop from `0` to `x` of whatever you pass in. So that loop is going to loop through all the indices of the columns in the outer loop.

---

Edit:
To change your code so it supports sub-lists of different lengths in your grid, you should get the length of each sub-list inside the list instead of only the length of the first sub-list. To do this you have to swap the order of your for loops like so:

```
def gridOutput(grid):
    for i in range(len(grid)):
        print()
        for s in range(len(grid[i])): # Get length of current sub-list
            print(grid[i][s], end='')
```

Comment: So len(grid) is getting the amount of lists within the list? and len(grid[0] is getting the amount of value within the lists that are within the list? I think it's making sense

Comment: @AlexHall Yeah that's correct. Except it is only getting the amount of values in the _first_ list because it gets it at index 0.

Comment: How come when I change index 0 to another integer, the output is exactly the same?

Comment: @AlexHall that is because your sub-lists all have the same length in your grid. If you had one of the sub-lists have more/less elements it would return that length.

Comment: Added one more value to the list at index[0], this means the length is 7. So when the second loop is called it would error because the other sub-lists only contain 6 values. When it gets the first value in the first for loop does it go to the second loop straight away?

Comment: Yes that error is expected because usually it makes things more complicated if your sub-lists have different lengths. To fix that you can swap the two `for` loops you have so that you loop by the rows in the outer loop and get the length of each of those rows instead. And yes it does go to second for loop and goes through all its values before iterating to the next step in the for loop.

Comment: I swapped the for loops round but still got the index error, I will try and figure this one out

Comment: @AlexHall I showed an example in my updated answer. You can't use one index as the length for all your sub-lists since they are different.

Comment: What the example is doing is printing all the values in each sub-list. [0,0] [1,0] [2,0] [3,0] [4,0]

Answer (score 2):

it basically prints out each element from 2 dimensional list
grid[0] => ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']
len(grid[0]) => 6
for s in range(len(grid[0])) => s=0, 1... to 5
you can use numpy to clean to code

Answer (score 1):

`len(grid[0])` gets the number of elements in the first row of your grid. 
In this case 6 => the number of columns.
So the first loop runs 6 times, and each iteration creates a second loop: 
`for i in range(len(grid))`

`len(grid)` gets the number of elements in the grid itself, in your case 9 => the number of rows.

Quick walkthough:

In the first iteration s=0, i=0 => first column in first line
In the second iteration s=0, i=1 => fist column in second line
and so on...

Hope this helps.